# $state and $stateProvider unusual behaviour while using an infinitescroll and a for loop

Tags: angularjs, for-loop, ionic-framework, infinite-scroll

I am having some trouble understanding the difference between all those `$state`, `$stateProvider` and `$routeProvider`.

The problem is that I am trying to implement an infinite-scroll in a simple app with posts. Since I managed to do that, the nested urls for more info about the post are not working. Here is a link from plnkr.co (http://embed.plnkr.co/66hgiIxNGTXOuVZgqKvZ/preview)

When on the feed tab everything seems fine, but when a link is clicked, empty page is displayed.

Comment: why don't create a different controller for the `tabs.details`

Comment: why is this more helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me try to make it simple.

### $stateProvider

To maintain application's state and provide a basic block to configure URL to represent view accordingly.

Each part of the state represents.

- url : The URL route that can be accessed via href properties
- templateUrl: The path to the view template HTML file
- controller : The controller to be used in this view

### $urlRouterProvider

Simply use for routing the user to specified url. where .otherwise method do route to the default url when the path doesn't match any of the urls you configured.

in your example you should handle the parameter in your controller to render the detail page.

I recommend you to follow this [example](http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/navigation-and-routing-part-2/) to understand how navigation and routing can simply implement in your application.

Comment: Got that, thanks a lot for the clear explanation, however, when I followed the example, I couldn't get my code working again. Here is a link from plnkr.co, again http://embed.plnkr.co/66hgiIxNGTXOuVZgqKvZ/preview Can you please tell me what I am missing now, this thing is driving me crazy

Comment: Updated your plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/Rrn6EA0nidatGWjMlwkw?p=preview Please check I modified your code little.

Comment: There are interesting changes, in the detail.html file too. Thank you for helping me, much appreciated.